# delete row with ajax - getting row id into ajax data parameters

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

What i've tried so far:
When I add the id to the data parameters with Javascript the row isn't deleted. When I add id in with php echo $id it deletes the wrong row. 
How can i properly add id to ajax data for the row I am deleting?

my code

(dbconnect code omitted)

```
$sql = "SELECT id, product_id, price, quantity FROM tbl_cart WHERE member_id = '$member_id' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


echo "<table class='anyClass'>";
echo "<tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Product</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         <th>Remove</th>
         <th>Add</th>

    </tr>";
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $id = $row['id'];

  echo "<tr> 
          <td>".$row['id']."</td>  
          <td>".$row['product_id']."</td>
          <td>".'$'.$row['price']."</td> 
          <td>".$row['quantity']."</td>
          <td><span class='delete' id='<?php echo $id; ?>'>Delete</span> 
</td>     
      </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
$conn->close()]

?>
```

My AJAX/JQUERY script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 // Delete 
 $('.delete').click(function(){
 var el = this;
 var id = this.id;

/* This code doesn't seem to work. Not sure why the author used split()
var splitid = id.split("_");

// Delete id
var deleteid = splitid[0];
*/

// AJAX Request
$.ajax({
url: 'remove.php',
type: 'POST',
data: { id:8},
success: function(response){

// Removing row from HTML Table
$(el).closest('tr').css('background','tomato');
$(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function(){ 
 $(this).remove();
});
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is where I got the code from http://makitweb.com/how-to-delete-record-from-mysql-table-with-ajax/#comment-903

Comment: just take out this hardcoded parameters `id:8` to the `id` that was clicked, then prepare your deletion php script that will be called with the asynchronous request, get the id `$_POST['id']` in the script

Answer (score 0):

First of all your doing wrong here.

```
data: { id:8}
```

Since the id you want to delete is hardcoded this will delete the same ID all the time.

For me the best thing to do here is like this.

```
echo "<tr> 
          <td>".$row['id']."</td>  
          <td>".$row['product_id']."</td>
          <td>".'$'.$row['price']."</td> 
          <td>".$row['quantity']."</td>
          <td><span class='delete' data-id=".$id.">Delete</span></td>     
      </tr>";
```

In this approach I am going to use the [.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Delete 
    $('.delete').click(function(){
        var el = this;
        var id = $(el).data('id');

        // AJAX Request
        $.ajax({
            url: 'remove.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id: id },
            success: function(response){
                // Removing row from HTML Table
                $(el).closest('tr').css('background','tomato');
                $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function(){ 
                 $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

So in the script js/jQuery we are going to get the value of attribute data-id from our span element now it will dynamically get the id of the row.

Comment: I tried the code you provided but it didn't remove the row from mysql. Is it possible there is something else wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in the code. It was here:

```
 <td><span class='delete' id='<?php echo $id; ?>'>Delete</span>
```

since I was already in php all I had to do was change that to this:

```
 <td><span class='delete' id= $id >Delete</span>
```

and it started deleting my rows in mysql.